# How to host multiple websites on different folders on a VPS?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, virtualhost, vps

I have a `domain1.com` pointing to my VPS server (I just specified the IP address in an `A` entry). More specifically the `domain1.com` is pointing to folder `/var/www/html` of my VPS.

I want to host another website on this VPS with domain name: `domain2.com`

My idea is to create a new directory: `/var/www/html2`, put the code of the new website in it, and then to redirect `domain2.com` to this folder.

But, I don't see how to do this by adding a `A` (DNS) entry. Also, is there not a solution to work with `.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of it you've probably configured your main server config for `domain1.com`. This is OK if you are only hosting 1 site on your server, but if you are hosting multiple websites (different domains) then you need to configure *virtual hosts* instead. One for `domain1.com` and another for `domain2.com`, etc.

You've probably put the necessary directives (ie. `ServerName`, `DocumentRoot` etc.) for `domain1.com` directly in the main server config, these need to be moved to a `<VirtualHost>` container instead.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted
        # Enable .htaccess overrides if required
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html2

    <Directory /var/www/html2>
        Require all granted
        # Enable .htaccess overrides if required
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Add the same `A` record for both domains. (You'll probably want to do the same for the www subdomain as well, or create a `CNAME` record.) So both domains point to the same IP address (ie. your server). Apache can then determine which virtual host to route the request to by comparing `Host` header on the request (HTTP 1.1) with the `ServerName` (or `ServerAlias`) directives inside the `<VirtualHost>` containers.

It's usual to have the `<VirtualHost>` containers in a separate `.conf` file that is *included* later in the main server config using the `Include` directive.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include

---

**UPDATE:**

> Also, is there not a solution to work with `.htaccess` ?

You don't implement virtual hosts using `.htaccess`. With `.htaccess` you can rewrite the URL so you can simulate something similar (with a single virtual host that is serving multiple domains) but that is not necessary here and not the way it should be done if you are hosting entirely separate sites.

Comment: Hello, I will try your solution now, thanks !

Comment: @ailauli69 Note that there are other directives you may want/need to add to each `<VirtualHost>`. For instance, you may want to have separate error and access logs for each vHost etc. (See the `ErrorLog` and `TransferLog` directives etc). And if you have SSL certs then these need to be configured with additional `<VirtualHost>` containers for port 443 (default), as opposed to port 80 (HTTP) as used above. etc.

Comment: Indeed I get an internal Internal Server Error, do I have to add the VirtualHost 443 ALONG with the VirtualHost 80 ? or do I have to replace it ?

Comment: The `<VirtualHost *:443>` would be added in addition. But just get port 80 working first, implementing SSL/HTTPS is an entire other step and is a huge topic just to itself. Check the details of the "Internal Server Error" in your server's error log.